# iOS Minimize view and all subviews to top left

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a `UIView` with a few subviews (and a few subviews in those). I am trying to minimize this entire view into the top left of the screen until it reaches a certain size (20 x 20) but am having trouble doing just that.

I first tried `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];` but this didn't resize the subviews. Also, due to the padding and amount of other subviews, it would be very hard to set each subview frame to some new size and make it all work well.

I then tried this code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

[self.myCardsCarousel.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
[self.myCardsCarousel setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0f, 0.0f)];

CGRect addCardsButtonFrame = self.addCardsButton.frame;
addCardsButtonFrame.size.height = 0.0f;

[self.addCardsButton setFrame:addCardsButtonFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But this doesn't minimize to the top left of the screen. Instead, it minimizes to the dead center of the screen.

How can I anchor this to the top left of the screen? Also, how can I stop a `CGAffineTransformMakeScale()` when the view reaches a certain size?

Comment: Sorry, I have not enough time to post a full answer, just some hints: If you want to scale and move your view, use a combined transform, e.g. CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.2, 0.2), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-160, -320))

Once the animation is in progress you cannot halt it, when the scale factor reaches a certain value. Just calculate the correct destination scale x and y factors and pass them into the CGAffineTransformMakeScale function.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create a snapshot of the view, and animate the snapshot into the corner (assuming that it's ok for the minimized view to be static). The general sequence of events is

- create a snapshot of the parent view into a memory bitmap
- create a UIImageView from the snapshot
- position the UIImageView in front of the parent view
- hide the parent view using its `hidden` property
- animate the UIImageView into the corner

To restore the view

- animate the UIImageView back to its original location
- unhide the parent view
- remove the UIImageView and discard it

To start, you need a property for the UIImageView

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *snapshotView;
```

Here's the code to minimize the view

```
// create a snapshot image of the parent view
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( self.parentView.bounds.size, YES, 0 );
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.parentView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// create a UIImageView from the snapshot
self.snapshotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.parentView.frame];
self.snapshotView.image = snapshot;
[self.view addSubview:self.snapshotView];

// hide the parent view in place, while animating the snapshot view into the corner
self.parentView.hidden = YES;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
animations:^
{
     self.snapshotView.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 20, 20 );
}
completion:nil];
```

Here's the code to restore the view

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
animations:^
{
    // animate the snapshot view back to original size
    self.snapshotView.frame = self.parentView.frame;
}
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    // reveal the parent view and discard the snapshot view
    self.parentView.hidden = NO;
    [self.snapshotView removeFromSuperview];
    self.snapshotView = nil;
}];
```